# Apache Thrift Service Auto Discovery

Tags: service, thrift, service-discovery

I want to develop some local network services using apache thrift. There should be multiple services waiting for ONE master to connect to them and use them exclusively until the master releases them. The services are written in multiple languages.

The choice to use thrift was done because I need some simple remote procedure call mechansim for communication between the services that is fast and supports multiple languages. While thrift is good for RPC, I need some mechanism to locate the service TCP addresses and ports via some auto-discovery mechanism before to be able to connect the thrift server/clients with each other without hardwiring the addresses.

What are the possibilities for auto-discovering of such sort of services do I have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing which you just plug into your scheme of things. You can build something similar using Apache ZooKeeper. Netflix's curator provides a good set of tools to build this, on top of ZooKeeper. See https://github.com/Netflix/curator